# How to split a string but keep the text just before the delimiter

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
const inputString = 'Crew: CAP(X): Ches, Ben, FO: Smith, Matthew, FO(T,P): Singh, Sushant';
```

I want to split this string so that the output is like so:

```
[
  'Crew',
  'CAP(X): Ches, Ben, ',
  'FO: Smith, Matthew, ',
  'FO(T,P): Singh, Sushant'
]
```

So split but take the text immediately before.

I tried this:

```
const result = inputString.split(/(?<=: )/);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ScottHunter happy now

Comment: How do you know where to split the string? It seems a bit arbitrary at the moment.

Comment: This looks more involved than just *splitting* the string.  What you have here appears to be a custom data format, and you'd parse it based on whatever the rules of that data format are.  (If the source of this data could produce a more standard format, that would be ideal.)  What are those rules?  This looks like something you'd need to split in a variety of ways to tokenize it and then perform logic on the resulting array(s) of elements, finding where colon tokens are and tracking both forward and backward from there to define the results.

Comment: So think about what splitting a string returns and how do we access the parts of that?

Comment: @DBS, its always going to be in the same format, so split at the : and the text directly attached to it

Comment: That's not an easy thing to process, as the character you want to split on is _different_ for the different groups (`:` for the first then `,`), which you could get around by splitting out the first section (`Crew`) then parsing the second part separately, but also _both_ of those delimiters are used _within_ the groups in the second part (i.e. there are some `,` you want to split on and some you don't). Maybe be more explicit about the structure of **what you want to extract**, rather than thinking about "splitting": https://regex101.com/r/edYUnS/1.

Comment: Do you have any control over the input string? I would start with fixing that so it's clearer.

Comment: @mykaf no, I am an airline pilot, this is the crew string which attached to our flight export, which I am trying to split apart and process. The format is always the same ie : and any text directly connected to the : is the rank and anything following the name

Comment: @jonrsharpe The structure I want is as I have posted rank: name etc etc

Comment: Yes, and if you follow the link you can see that's exactly what's pulled out. My point is that thinking of this as _splitting_, then trying to keep some things both sides of what you split on, is fundamentally misguided.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, yeah that seems to be working. I'll have a play around. How should I be looking at it then? I am just a pilot trying to do some coding as well. Lets not be brutal :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a tricky one due to "Crew" not being the same as the rest of the string, plus all the additional commas and colons. Here's my attempt:

```js
const inputString = 'Crew: CAP(X): Ches, Ben, FO: Smith, Matthew, FO(T,P): Singh, Sushant';

//"Crew' is the outlier, so let's remove it for now and let's split on spaces
let formattedString = inputString.replace("Crew: ","").split(" ");

//We'll start with "Crew"
const finalOutput = ["Crew"];

let idx = 0;
formattedString.forEach(
    fs => {
    //":" indicates title, so we'll make this into a new item in the array by increasing idx and initializing the array item at this index
    if (fs.includes(":")) {
      idx++;
      finalOutput[idx] = "";
    }

        //add the current word at this array index
    finalOutput[idx] += fs;
    
  }
);
//console.log(finalOutput)
//add the spaces back to the colons and strings
finalFinalOutput = finalOutput.map(
    i => i.replaceAll(":",": ").replaceAll(",",", ")
);

console.log(finalFinalOutput)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split it by space, then loop over it,
if contains `:`, push a new item, otherwise just concatenate it.

Something like below,

```js
const inputString = 'Crew: CAP(X): Ches, Ben, FO: Smith, Matthew, FO(T,P): Singh, Sushant'

// split by space
const words = inputString.split(/\s/)

let output = []
let res = ''

for (const word of words) {
    if (word.includes(':')) {
        // add new item to output if : is found and reset res
        if ( res !== '' ) 
            output.push(res)
        res = word
    } else {
        //concatenate with current res
        res += ' ' + word
    }
}

// push the last res
output.push( res )

console.log( output )
```